# Some Android Unity Games can't support mouse click?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mouse

On Android, I found some Unity Games can not support mouse click(e.g. com.defiantdev.skisafari), I can move mouse cursor, but buttons don't response when I click them. But most games can support mouse. I can use mouse click buttons like finger touch.

I am not familiar with Unity. So I am confused that why some games can not support mouse? Does Unity can not support mouse default? Developers need implements the function by themselves?

If a game can not support mouse, Can I modify it to support easily?

Thanks.

Comment: this is probably a design choice or an oversight. No you cannot modify the finished product but if you have access to the source code (open source games) then you can tinker with it.

Comment: In Unity, it is up to the game developer to implement mouse control if they want to support it. Most developers are probably not thinking about mouse control on mobile, because it is so rare.

Comment: But I found most Unity games can support mouse, a few games can not support. So I think may Unity can support mouse controller by default.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Your means is if a button created in Unity, by default, it only support finger touch, and can not clicked by mouse?

Comment: Unity has built-in support for buttons that can be put in the UI, but their performance is poor, especially on mobile. Most developers program their own buttons from scratch, and it is up to them to put in support for accepting mouse clicks. But in fact, I am not even sure if Unity supports mice for the Android platform. Never tested it.

Comment: Unity supports mouse clicks on all platforms. When in mobile development however, what would be considered a left or right mouse click is transformed into one and two fingers touch respectively.

Comment: We tested these games on Android TV, so We need them work by mouse click...

Comment: Only way to find out is by testing it I guess. Try running  Debug.Log(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) (if you have access to the debugger, otherwise just print it using a GUI Label) and see if it changes to true when you click the left mouse button.

Comment: I had the same scenario with this topic you're discussing. You see, I discovered by accident, when I test run the Android app powered by Unity, a mouse click can be treated as finger touch. OnMouseDown() and OnMouseUp() works as well in Android Jellybean. But, I haven't tested yet on ICS. That will be required more study about mouse click as Android touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity can support mouse clicks. However, it is possible that the developer of the games you are playing did not include the functions that support the mouse.

```
void OnMouseDown() 
{
  // User clicked the mouse.
}

void OnMouseUp() 
{

}
```

**This is how you find the exact mouse button you clicked.**

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        Debug.Log("Pressed right click.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");
```

**If you have access to the source code, then you can make the game do anything and everything you want!**

[Unity's API -- Mouse Subsection](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Mouse)